# ionic 2 native facebook force inappbrowser authentication

Tags: android, facebook, ionic-framework

I have a problem with my production app, i have oauth with facebook in my app when i sign the app and use facebook lite application and try to login this returns an error:

> webpage is not available
>
> the webpage at
>
> fbconnect://success#status........
>
> could not be loaded because:
>
> net: ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

This problem is only if i have installed facebook lite, with facebook app and without facebook apps it works fine, my question is, if is posible to force inappbrowser authentication as if facebook apps were not installed.

i follow [ionic docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/facebook/) i try edit my config.xml with:

> allow-intent href="fbconnect://*"  launch-external="true" />

but doesn't work, my only solution it's force appbrowser auth. any ideas or solutions?